# Cross-domain error using RequireJS on IE9

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, xdomainrequest

I am using RequireJS to load several (xdomain) files from domainB to domainA including the AngularJS framework as follows:

```
var basePath = DOMAIN_B;

require.config({
                baseUrl: basePath+"js/scripts/",

            paths: {
                'angular': '../lib/angular/angular',
                'angular-route': '../lib/angular/angular-route',
                'angularAMD': '../lib/requirejs/angular-amd',

                'ControllerVideos': 'controller/controller-videos',
                'ControllerFriendProfile': 'controller/controller-friend-profile',
                'ControllerAchieve': 'controller/controller-achieve',
                'ControllerDiary': 'controller/controller-diary',
                'ControllerFriends': 'controller/controller-friends',
                'ControllerProfile': 'controller/controller-profile',
                'ControllerLanding': 'controller/controller-landing',
                'ControllerMain': 'controller/controller-main'
            },

            // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
            shim: {
                'angularAMD': ['angular'],
                'angular-route': ['angular']
            },

            // kick start application
            deps: ['app']
        });
```

The line `deps:['app']` is throwing an 'access denied' error in IE9. This doesn't happen in IE10, Chrome or FireFox.

Does anyone know why this is?